# does someone gifting you something send the transaction to your email on xbox

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online

So my friend wants to gift me a megalodon card in gta 5. the problem is is that my parents don't know that I play gta 5 and I don't want them to know that I play gta 5. will the the gift show up?